# Are users allowed to promote their YouTube channel?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013655/how-to-export-hdfs-data-into-mysql/34013762#34013762) in the review queue.

The user gives a vague answer (I am not really familiar with this topic), and afterwards promotes a playlist in his YouTube channel.

The playlist is about [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop) as is the question. It is also rather lengthy and seems to be of OK-quality. Should it be allowed to remain?

Comment: It is OK as long as they answer the question satisfactorily and then add a link to the video (to either give credit if it is uploaded by a different person or   if it includes additional information which the poster couldn't cover in his answer). If the answer is just a link, then it deserves to be deleted

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Your comment is a much more clear than the accepted answer and in fewer words.

Comment: Something I would like to see more often is kind of a short disclaimer when the linked resource (video, book, ...) has been created (is under some control of) by the very same poster. That way I can judge potential conflicts of interest (even commercial ones) better and there surely is a bit of an interest there to draw as many visitors as possible to that resource usually.

Answer (score 29):

**Update**
Just want to clarify that posting YouTube video link is allowed, if the video explains the answer in details. That too when you've explained it in brief. The answer itself should be sufficient to solve the issue. My point is you can't post a link to a whole channel and expect someone to find a specific video which may or may not solve it.

**Original Post**

No, they can't promote their Youtube channel. They can mention a specific video which might be explaining things in details. However the answer itself should be sufficient to solve the original question. For more information read [how not to promote your own products](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)  and [how not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

I have removed the youtube channel link from the answer, because I don't think it was necessary for the post. You can either raise a flag or edit the answer yourself, only if you're sure the link is not required for the answer at all.

Comment: I've down voted this answer because your first sentence is flat wrong when taken out of context and because "necessity" and "requirement" are absolutely the wrong terms for deciding whether a link should be left alone or not. You *can* promote other resources that are *relevant* to the question. (If they happen to be your resources, you're required to disclose that.) Relevance is the deciding factor, not whether it is "necessary" or "required." Everything else you say is correct, but it's important to be very clear on Meta.

Comment: @jpmc26 what I meant is, you're free to promote your own video (with disclosure) if it explains and support the answer. But why the hell they need to put a link of a whole channel for that? I am sure the channel is not dedicated towards solving a single issue. It's my take on this. I don't mind the downvote :-)

Comment: You've missed my point entirely. I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm saying you need to clarify your answer; some of the statements in it are misleading. (Notably, the first sentence of the answer is *very* misleading.)

Comment: @jpmc26 Point noted. I have added a clarification.

Comment: I would also add the behavior guide, which pretty much sums up why you did the right thing to remove the link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score -1):

I am new to stackoverflow and there are 2 links I have added as part of the answer. First one explains the question, how to load data into HDFS using sqoop, second one is playlist which explains Sqoop in detail. Any ways I will try to provide links to my videos if the video provides the exact answer to the question. As YouTube is gaining momentum to share the knowledge in video format, probably you need to update the "informed" content so that people are aware of it. Also, if stackoverflow provides capability to share in professional network linkedIn it will be great.

Comment: You can put whatever you want on your user profile. Additionally, if you want to link to a video, it would be especially useful for you to actually link to the *time* where you address the relevant issue, unless the video is short.

Comment: An answer must be able to stand on its own merit, without external images, external fiddles, external articles, or external videos.